# MongoDB Social Network Adding Followers

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm implementing a social network in MongoDB and I need to keep track of Followers and Following for each User. When I search for Users I want to display a list like Facebook with the User Name, Picture and number of Followers & Following. If I just wanted to display the User Name and Picture (info that doesn't change) it would be easy, but I also need to display the number of Followers & Following (which changes fairly regularly).

My current strategy is to embed the People a User follows into each User Document:

```
firstName: "Joe",
lastName: "Bloggs",
follows: [
 {
   _id: ObjectId("520534b81c9aac710d000002"),
   profilePictureUrl: "https://pipt.s3.amazonaws.com/users/xxx.jpg",
   name: "Mark Rogers",
 },
 {
   _id: ObjectId("51f26293a5c5ea4331cb786a"),
   name: "The Palace Bar",
   profilePictureUrl: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/businesses/xxx.jpg",
 }
]
```

The question is - What is the best strategy to keep track of the number of Followers & Following for each User?

If I include the number of Follows / Following as part of the embedded document i.e.

```
follows: [
{
  _id: ObjectId("520534b81c9aac710d000002"),
  profilePictureUrl: "https://pipt.s3.amazonaws.com/users/xxx.jpg",
  name: "Mark Rogers",
  **followers: 10,**
  **following: 400**
}
```

then every time a User follows someone requires multiple updates across all the embedded documents.

Since the consistency of this data isn't really important (i.e. Showing someone I have 10 instead of 11 followers isn't the end of the world), I can queue this update. Is this approach ok or can anyone suggest a better approach ?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  Think about which calculation is performed more - determining the number of followers/following or changing number of followers/following?  Even if you're caching the output of the # of followers/following calculation it's still going to be performed one or two orders of magnitude more often than changing the number.

Also, think about the opposite.  If you really need to display the number of followers/following for each of those users, you'll have to then do an aggregate on each load (or cache it somewhere, but you're still doing a lot of calcs).

**Option 1**:  Cache the number of followers/following in the embedded document.
Upsides:  Can display stats in O(1) time
Downsides:  Requires O(N) time to follow/unfollow

**Option 2**:  Count the number of followers/following on each page view (or cache invalidation)
Upsides:  Can follow/unfollow in O(1) time
Downsides:  Requires O(N) time to display

Add in the fact that follower/following stats can be eventually consistent whereas the counts have to be displayed on demand and I think it's a pretty easy decision to cache it.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback Mason. I have implemented Option 1, have a look below. Interested to hear any thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

I've gone ahead and implement the update followers/following based on the same strategy recommended by Mason (Option 1). Here's my code in NodeJs and Mongoose and using the AsyncJs Waterfall pattern in case anyone is interested or has any opinions. I haven't implemented queuing yet but the plan would be to farm most of this of to a queue.

```
async.waterfall([

        function (callback) {

            /** find & update the person we are following */
            Model.User
                .findByIdAndUpdate(id,{$inc:{followers:1}},{upsert:true,select:{fullName:1,profilePictureUrl:1,address:1,following:1,followers:1}})
                .lean()
                .exec(callback);
        },
        function (followee, callback) {

            /** find & update the person doing the following */
            var query = {
                $inc:{following:1},
                $addToSet: { follows: followee}
            }

            Model.User
                .findByIdAndUpdate(credentials.username,query,{upsert:true,select:{fullName:1,profilePictureUrl:1,address:1,following:1,followers:1}})
                .lean()
                .exec(function(err,follower){
                    callback(err,follower,followee);
                });

        },
        function(follower,followee,callback){

            /** update the following count */
            Model.User
                .update({'follows._id':follower.id},{'follows.$.following':follower.following},{upsert:true,multi:true},function(err){
                    callback(err,followee);
                });
        },
        function(followee,callback){
            /** update the followers count */
            Model.User
                .update({'follows._id':followee.id},{'follows.$.followers':followee.followers},{upsert:true,multi:true},callback);
        }
    ], function (err) {
        if (err)
            next(err);
        else {
            res.send(HTTPStatus.OK);
            next();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Make sure you handle your error cases.  For example if there's a failure in your second update then we end up with a one-way follow instead of a reciprocal follow and the user we're following has their `followers` number become out of sync.  The easiest thing is probably to track where errors occur and then attempt to rollback anything you've done.  You'll probably also want to setup a background process that runs outside the system to ensure that everything remains consistent.